# Can't import packages in VSCode Java project

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, import, package

I cannot import packages in my Java classes in VSCode. I type out the statement, `import db.engine.*;` (in the 'GlobalSetters' class), and try to "Run Code" in the GlobalSetters class. An error is then returned in the console:

`GlobalSetter.java:3: error: package db.engine does not exist`

`import db.engine.*;`

The issue started in another project, then I copied all classes to a test project to try and figure the issue out. I've installed the 'Extension Pack for Java' extension and I am trying to run the code with the 'Code Runner' extension.

I've been at this for a while now and there aren't any issues being identified in the import statement itself. Any ideas as to why it continually returns this error?

[image: Package structure of the test project.]

Comment: it probably is the code runner extension. I personally have had some bad experiences with it. The java extension by default should have a "run" button near the top of the `main` method. Also, you might also need to configure the source directory to make it work as expected. You might want to have  look at [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java) as well.

Comment: You were exactly correct! Code runner was causing some... strange errors. Now that I've disabled it and 'Run Java' as you said it all works perfectly! Thank you very much for the help and the link to the guide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to [Mubin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12726948/mubin) for the answer! It turns out the 'Code Runner' extension was causing some serious issues. In addition, I had to select the drop down arrow next to the run button in the top right of the workspace. Then select 'Run Java' instead of "Run Code". Disabling 'Code Runner' removes the 'Run Code' option and replaces it with 'Run Java', however.

Comment: You can accept this answer to mark the question as resolved.

Comment: I have tried but it is holding me to a 2 day wait that has 21 hours left...